# Total time registered user have been online

Tags: php

I am right now programming a community in PHP, but i'm stuck, as i can't figure out, how to see how long my users have spent on the site. It should be showed on their profile, such as: "This user has spent 10 hours and 10 minutes on sitename". But i have no idea, how i should make this!

I think of adding a row to my users table (In my MySQL database) called 'last_visit_time' to store the time the user last time visited a site on my website and one called 'total_time' to store total time spent online.

Then everytime a user loads a page, it first check if you'r logged in. Then if you are, it first checks if('last_visit_time' + 2 minutes >= $current_time) then, if that is true, it add the difference of 'last_visit_time' and $current_time to the 'total_time' row. After that, it updates the 'last_visit_time' to the currently time.

This will give a 2 minutes tolerence, for users to visit a new page - and then it add the time spent on the previous page (If it's under 2 minutes). As what i can figure out, there is no way the users can cheat with this script, because you will be gained nothing by spam-updating the pages or visiting the page in 2 windows (On same account).

But how can you actually get the difference between currently time, and last_visit_time, and check if there has passed more than 2 minutes! Or should i make this a different way?

I'm quite open for suggestions and especially help, as it is needed very much.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this with easy script. I have time "tollerance" of X minutes. Every time, user open another page, before page is "rendered" I run script "update user time". I have stored last time of user activity, now take current time and make difference, which gives me time since last "update". This time I add to user time spend on my site.

For measuring time, I use simple UNIX time stamp, which is easy to deal with. Just substract two numbers and get time in seconds since last activity.

Hovewer, it has one drawback.If user goes somewhere else. He can be hours on single page and then go out. This will never be counted this way. For this to also count, you will have to use JavaScript and timer, that will launch script via AJAX every now and then and do the same as if user "click" on another page on your web.